# Как прервать выполнение Task если метод в другом классе?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, task, .net-5

Доброго времени суток!

Пытаюсь подружить один прибор (векторный анализатор цепей) и программу(WPF) для обработки и расчетов.
Все измерения проводятся в классе AutoMeasure. Нажимаю кнопочку на форме - создается объект класса AutoMeasure и далее в нем вызывается метод в отдельном Task, который производит измерение на приборе посредством SCPI комманд.

```
    private void OnQuality0MeasurmentCommandExecuted(object p)
    {
        
        Task taskQ0Measure = new Task(() => DeviceResponse = autoMeasure.QualityMeasurment().ToString());

        try
        {
           taskQ0Measure.Start(); // запускаю таск с методом измерения
           /////////// ПРОБЛЕМНОЕ МЕСТО ///////////////////////////////////////
           Task.WaitAll(taskQ0Measure); // надо подождать когда закончиться все

           F0n = autoMeasure.FrequnecyCenter / 1e9;  
           F0low = autoMeasure.FrequnecyLow / 1e9;
           F0high = autoMeasure.FrequnecyHigh / 1e9;
           Q0n = autoMeasure.QualityFactor;
          
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка ВАЦ!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
    }
```

В указанном проблемном месте - может возникнуть ситуация, когда прибор по каким то причинам отвалился/отключился/сломался/сгорел.

В классе AutoMeasure есть публичное свойство ViStatus status для отслеживания состояния прибора

```
class AutoMeasure
{
    public double FrequnecyCenter { get; set; }       
    public double FrequnecyLow { get; set; }      
    public double FrequnecyHigh { get; set; }       
    public object DeviceResponse { get; set; }

    public StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder(1000);
    public ViSession rm, rsrc;
    public ViStatus status;

    public AutoMeasure()
    {

    } ....далее все методы.......
}
```

В свойстве ViStatus status - во время успешной работы постоянно присваивается строка "VI_SUCCES" либо что то другое, когда ошибка. Иными словами условие прерывания в проблемном месте должно быть что то типа

```
if (status!="VI_SUCCES") //  то прерываем выполнение всех методов в классе AutoMeasure
```

Вопрос в том, как и куда что добавить (токен отмены? в MainWindowViewModel, или в класс AutoMeasure? или еще куда то) или как то по другому решить задачу, чтобы когда прибор "отвалился" - программа не зависала. Так как когда прибор отваливается, внутри метода autoMeasure.QualityMeasurment()  - происходит очень много кода и комманд SCPI, там внутри писать проверки и завершение метода в случае ошибки - это очень гемморная и долгая работа но status вроде всегда обновляется и всегда доступен снаружи.

Что можно предпринять в данной ситуации?
Заранее всем спасибо)

******* Добавляю больше кода)

```
// XAML Код кнопки
<Button                                       
    Style="{DynamicResource ButtonRoundVNA}"   
    FontSize="12" FontWeight="Light" 
    Background="#D99594" 
    Command="{Binding Quality0Measurment}" // комманда запуска измерения
    IsEnabled="{Binding VNATrigger}" > // тригер разблокировки/блокировки кнопки
        <Button.Content>
            <TextBlock Margin="0,-2,0,0" FontSize="14" FontWeight="DemiBold">
                Запуск измерения <Run FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" > R0</Run>
            </TextBlock>
        </Button.Content>
</Button>
//////////////////////////////////////////
// Код в MainWindowViewModel                        
        public ICommand Quality0Measurment { get; }
        private void OnQuality0MeasurmentCommandExecuted(object p)
        {
            CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            Task taskQ0Measure = new Task(() => DeviceResponse = autoMeasure.QualityMeasurment().ToString(),cts.Token);   
            try
            {
                taskQ0Measure.Start();
                /////// ПРОБЛЕМНОЕ МЕСТО /////// - куда здесь воткнуть токен?
                Task.WaitAll(taskQ0Measure);
                bool succesQ = autoMeasure.QualityMeasureCheck(FLow:autoMeasure.FrequnecyLow, FHigh:autoMeasure.FrequnecyHigh, FCenter:autoMeasure.FrequnecyCenter);

                if (succesQ == true)
                {
                    F0n = autoMeasure.FrequnecyCenter / 1e9;   //
                    F0low = autoMeasure.FrequnecyLow / 1e9;
                    F0high = autoMeasure.FrequnecyHigh / 1e9;
                    Q0n = autoMeasure.QualityFactor;
                }
                else
                {
                    F0n = -1;
                    F0low = -1;
                    F0high = -1;
                    Q0n = -1;
                }             
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка ВАЦ!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
        }
        private bool CanQuality0MeasurmentCommandExecute(object p) => true;

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
              Quality0Measurment = new LambdaCommand(OnQuality0MeasurmentCommandExecuted, CanQuality0MeasurmentCommandExecute);
        }
///// Класс AutoMeasure
class AutoMeasure
    {
        public double FrequnecyCenter { get; set; }
        public double FrequnecyLow { get; set; }
        public double FrequnecyHigh { get; set; }
        public double QualityFactor { get; set; }
        public object DeviceResponse { get; set; }
        public StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder(1000);
        public ViSession rm, rsrc;
        public ViStatus status;

        public AutoMeasure()
        {

        }

        public object QualityMeasurment()
        {
            ///// здесь идут SCPI комманды для общение с прибором, во время комманды или запроса может произойти зависание, и status становиться != "VI_SUCCES"
            status = Visa.Printf(rsrc, "*CLS\n");
            status = Visa.Printf(rsrc, ":INITiate:IMMediate\n");
            status = Visa.Queryf(rsrc, "*OPC?\n", "%T", __arglist(buff));
            status = Visa.Printf(rsrc, ":DISPlay:WINDow0:TRACe0:Y[:SCALe]:AUTO\n");
            // Комманды и дополнительных методов с SCPI коммандами тут исопльзуется значительно больше  
            ///////////////////////////////////
            // в итоге после успешного завершения всех комманд
            FrequnecyCenter = FCentrView;
            FrequnecyHigh = Fhighaproxim;
            FrequnecyLow = FLowView;
            QualityFactor = QView;

            DeviceResponse = status;
            return DeviceResponse;
        }
    }

internal class LambdaCommand : Command
    {
        private readonly Action<object> _Execute;
        private readonly Func<object, bool> _CanExecute;

        public LambdaCommand(Action<object> Execute, Func<object, bool> CanExecute = null)
        {
            _Execute = Execute ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(Execute));
            _CanExecute = CanExecute;
        }
        public override bool CanExecute(object parameter) => _CanExecute?.Invoke(parameter) ?? true;
        public override void Execute(object parameter) => _Execute(parameter);
    }
```

//Успешное выполнение SCPI комманд в коде во время отладки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129018/discussion-on-question-by------task--).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начнем с интерфейса. Ваша `LambdaCommand` хорошая, но она не умеет реагировать на ввод. Есть фишка, что когда вы жмете в окно мышкой или клавиатурой, можно обновлять `CanExecute` команды автоматически, класс дотнета `CommandManager` будет сам заниматься этим делом. Главное - правильно к нему привязаться.

Вот альтернатива, которую я [утащил у Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern#relaying-command-logic) и немного причесал код.

```cs
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute = null)
        => (_execute, _canExecute) = (execute, canExecute);

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        => _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);

    public void Execute(object parameter)
        => _execute(parameter);
}
```

То есть здесь наследуем не класс `Command` (кстати, что это?), а реализуем интерфейс `ICommand` полностью.

`CanExecute` - это блокировщик доступности кнопки. То есть вот это `IsEnabled="{Binding VNATrigger}"` - надо выкинуть, чтобы не мешать `CanExecute` команды работать.

```xml
<Button                                       
    Style="{DynamicResource ButtonRoundVNA}"   
    FontSize="12" FontWeight="Light" 
    Background="#D99594" 
    Command="{Binding Quality0Measurment}">
        <Button.Content>
            <TextBlock Margin="0,-2,0,0" FontSize="14" FontWeight="DemiBold">
                Запуск измерения <Run FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic"> R0</Run>
            </TextBlock>
        </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

---

Теперь работа с тасками и девайсом. Как я вижу, команды синхронные, то есть запустить в потоке можно. Еще вы утверждаете, что статус меняется, если что-то пошло не так. То есть сбой происходит до того как происходит зависание. Следовательно, вам стоит проверять статус после каждой команды. И если что-то пошло не так - сразу же бросать исключение. Давайте кстати его создадим.

```cs
public class AutoMeasureException : Exception
{
    public ViStatus Status { get; }

    public AutoMeasureException(ViStatus status) : base(status.ToString())
    {
        Status = status;
    }
}
```

Тогда можно будет реализовать выброс исключения при любом изменении статуса через свойство, не особо изменяя ваш существующий код.

```cs
class AutoMeasure
{
    public double FrequnecyCenter { get; set; }
    public double FrequnecyLow { get; set; }
    public double FrequnecyHigh { get; set; }
    public double QualityFactor { get; set; }
    public ViStatus DeviceResponse { get; set; }

    public StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder(1000);
    public ViSession rm, rsrc;

    private ViStatus status;
    public ViStatus Status {
        get => status;
        set
        {
            status = value;
            if (status != ViStatus.VI_SUCCESS) // можно дописать || !status.ToString().StartsWith("VI_SUCCESS_")
                throw new AutoMeasureException(value);
        }
    }

    public AutoMeasure()
    {

    }

    public ViStatus QualityMeasurment()
    {
        Status = Visa.Printf(rsrc, "*CLS\n");
        Status = Visa.Printf(rsrc, ":INITiate:IMMediate\n");
        Status = Visa.Queryf(rsrc, "*OPC?\n", "%T", __arglist(buff));
        Status = Visa.Printf(rsrc, ":DISPlay:WINDow0:TRACe0:Y[:SCALe]:AUTO\n");

        // ...

        FrequnecyCenter = FCentrView;
        FrequnecyHigh = Fhighaproxim;
        FrequnecyLow = FLowView;
        QualityFactor = QView;

        DeviceResponse = Status;
        return DeviceResponse;
    }
}
```

Теперь зависания не произойдет, так как выполнение метода будет немедленно остановлено выбросом исключения как только результат выполнения одной из команд будет отличный от успешного.

---

Теперь вернемся к команде. Будем так же запускать поток, только немного правильнее, без подвешивания интерфейса на время, пока он работает и дизаблить кнопку на время работы. При этом остальное приложение останется живым на время выполнения, даже если где-то в потоке что-то зависнет.

Теперь с новой командой напишу лямбду с "ленивой" инициализацией. И немного асинхронного программирования.

```cs
public bool VNATrigger { get; set; } // в свойствах у вас INPC реализация, не буду ее сюда дублировать
public ViStatus DeviceResponse { get; set; } // WPF UI прекрасно покажет значение перечисления без всяких ToString()

private ICommand _quality0Measurment;

public ICommand Quality0Measurment => _quality0Measurment ??= new RelayCommand(async parameter => 
{
    VNATrigger = false;
    try
    {
        DeviceResponse = await Task.Run(() => autoMeasure.QualityMeasurment()); // вот так вот просто

        bool succesQ = autoMeasure.QualityMeasureCheck(FLow: autoMeasure.FrequnecyLow, FHigh: autoMeasure.FrequnecyHigh, FCenter: autoMeasure.FrequnecyCenter);

        if (succesQ)
        {
            F0n = autoMeasure.FrequnecyCenter / 1e9;   //
            F0low = autoMeasure.FrequnecyLow / 1e9;
            F0high = autoMeasure.FrequnecyHigh / 1e9;
            Q0n = autoMeasure.QualityFactor;
        }
        else
        {
            F0n = -1;
            F0low = -1;
            F0high = -1;
            Q0n = -1;
        }
    }
    catch (AutoMeasureException ex)
    {
        // то есть тот самый Status из AutoMeasure приехал сюда. ex.Message тоже есть, допишите класс AutoMeasureException под себя
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Status.ToString(), "Ошибка ВАЦ!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error); 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }
    VNATrigger = true;
    CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested(); // эта команда заставляет CommandManager перезапросить CanExecute
}, parameter => VNATrigger);
```

`CancellationToken` по сути здесь и не нужен, так как отмена происходит только изнутри, не снаружи.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Исключение начал ловить, когда устройство внезапно отключилось) Долго не мог понять в чем дело, не работало, оказывается надо было команды SCPI слать не через status = Visa.Printf(rsrc, ":INITiate:IMMediate\n"); а Status как свойство.

Comment: @ЕвгенийФедоров да, именно так у меня и написано в коде. :)